# Angular composite (super) directive not allowing 2 way binding on component (child) directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I have a need to create a composite directive that incorporates separate fully functional directives.  One of my component directives adds an element to the dom and that element binds to a value in the component directive's controller.  When the composite directive adds the component directive in the compile function, it seems to work but the piece that has the 2 way binding in the component directive does not appear to get compiled and just renders the {{ctrl.value}} string on the screen.  I realize this is a bit convoluted so I have included a plunk to help clarify the issue.

```
 app.directive('compositeDirective', function($compile){
  return {
    compile: compileFunction
  }
  function compileFunction(element, attrs){
    attrs.$set("component-directive", "");
    element.removeAttr("composite-directive");
    element.after("<div>Component value when added in composite directive: {{compCtrl.myValue}}</div>");
    return { post: function(scope, element){
      $compile(element)(scope);
    }};
  }
});
app.directive('componentDirective', function(){
  return {
    controller: "componentController as compCtrl",
    link: link
  };
  function link(scope, element){
    element.after("<div>Component value: {{compCtrl.myValue}}</div>");
  }
});
app.controller('componentController', function(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.myValue = "Hello";
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/alO83j9Efz62VTKDOVgc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think any compilation will happen as a result of changes in the link function, unless you call $compile manually, i.e.,

```
app.directive('componentDirective', function($compile){
  return {
    controller: "componentController as compCtrl",
    link: link
  };
  function link(scope, element){
    var elm = $compile("<div>Component value: {{compCtrl.myValue}}</div>")(scope);
    element.append(elm);
  }
});
```

Updated plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/pIixQujs1y6mPMKT4zxK

You can also use a compile function instead of link: http://plnkr.co/edit/fjZMd4FIQ97oHSvetOgU

Also, make sure to use .append() instead of .after().

Comment: "append" was the key.  "after" worked when the component directive was a stand-alone.  However, when I tried to use it in the context of the composite the "append" was required.

Comment: I did a little more research.  For some reason, when I used the "append" function an ng-binding attribute was added.  I am not sure why the ng-binding was added with "append" and not with "after".